# Neo4J indexing using Blueprint API

Tags: nosql, neo4j, blueprint

any one used [TinkerPop's Blueprints](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/) API with Neo4J or OrientDB

Answer (score 1):

Well, Blueprints and Gremlin are built right into the Neo4j Server as a console, so you can use it in there ...

Answer (score 0):

OrientDB Graph Edition is available here: http://code.google.com/p/orient/downloads/list

You can then use Gremlin via OrientDB_Studio's (http://code.google.com/p/orient/wiki/OrientDB_Studio) console if you select "Gremlin" instead of "SQL" in the drop-down menu.

It also comes with a command line Gremlin console.